# Simulating constant Pixels-Per-Unit in game graphics at different "Zoom Levels"

Tags: opengl, graphics, rendering, shader, rasterizing

I'm currently trying to lay down the graphical style for a game environment I am working on. Meshes are rendered at a fairly low resolution in isometric to give a "sprite-like" appearance.

The issue is keeping the resolution I have picked to maintain the correct Pixels-Per-Unit in game. For example, here is a Cube rendered so that its top face is roughly equal to that of a 64 by 32px isometric tile: [Lets say this is Zoom Level x1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0vM4.png)

Now in an engine like Unity, I can play around with screen size and cameras to zoom in or out easily. But to keep the original rendering resolution, I can only think of forcing the player into Fullscreen, changing the screen-resolution, and allowing the scene to scale accordingly.

So to zoom in, I cut the resolution in half but bring the cube twice as close to the screen. This is the intended outcome: [Zoom Level x2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDT9y.png) (scaled in image editor).

The top face of the cube appears to still be 64 by 32px even though it actually takes up 128 by 64px on the screen.

---

I want to know if this effect can be simulated by writing my own shader and having some parameter for 'Zoom Level' (x1, x2, x4, x8). This way I don't have to play magic tricks with fullscreen resolution, and I can also let the screen size be independent of the "render resolution."

Zooming in with off the shelf shaders won't keep a fixed Pixels-Per-Unit, since the cube is closer and can take up more pixels on screen, its quality also increases. (I can only post 2 pictures at the time).

The higher quality of the rendered cube is nice and standard behavior, but it is not the intended effect. Think "nearest neighbor" scaling in image editing software. That is the kind of rendering I'm going after at zoom levels x2, x4, x8. Just in real-time.

I know it seems weird to want meshes to render like sprites, but this is a concept that interests me greatly as a 'look' for a game.

---

So can this be done at the shader level? I have looked into writing my own glsl shaders for OpenGL and am slowly learning the general flow of things.

Can I change how a shader rasterizes fragments to get that "nearest neighbor" sampling I'm going after?

Can a shader even interact with a parameter like "Zoom Level = 2" to change its behavior while rendering?

Or perhaps there are other ways to achieve this style of real-time rendering that I haven't come across?

And of course, is this even something that a shader *does*? I might be incorrect on what stage of the graphics pipeline this is handled at.

Comment: The easiest approach is probably to render to a lower resolution off-screen framebuffer (FBO), and then blit it to the window.

Comment: Why not just reduce the resolution of the back buffer and adapt viewport and the projection matrix? Then, the rasterizer will do the work for you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071090/low-resolution-in-opengl-to-mimic-older-games Both of you provided me with the right search terms to find part of the solution, the other part being figuring out how to pair it with interactivity for changing zoomlevel in game.